# Не работает json. success не отрабатывает, но в БД записывается

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

Есть html код:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" id="registration" method="post">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submit-reg" type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="registrationForm.js"></script>
```

Вот содержание скрипта registrationForm.js:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit-reg').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'form.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#registration').serialize(),
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg.success) {
          alert(msg.yes);
        } else {
          alert(msg.no);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Вот что возвращается из php:

```js
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if ($result) {
  $arr = array("success" => 1, "yes" => "Успешно");
  echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
  $arr = array("success" => 0, "no" => "Ошибка");
  echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

В БД значения пишутся, но я не могу получить массив обратно в скрипт, этот "success"(который в js) у меня вообще не отрабатывает, как-будто его не существует. Помогите найти ошибку или подскажите другой подход для получения данных из php обратно в js.

Answer (score 1):

Этот Ajax немного не так работает

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit-reg').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var request = $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'form.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#registration').serialize()
        });
        request.done(function(msg){console.log('done');});
        request.fail(function(msg){console.log('fail');});
    })
});
```

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, что вместо `console.log('done');` я могу подставить `alert(msg.yes);` ?

Comment: Тут дело не в методе `ajax`, а в ошибках на сервере. Нужно включить логирование ошибок PHP либо просматривать вкладку Network в браузере.

Comment: Да, посмотри что request.fail выдает, там уже можно будет понять куда дальше копать.